# What is this icon called in statusbar?

Tags: android

What is this called and what is use?[image]

Mobile is samsung galaxy A50s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a data saver Icon that comes with the Android Oreo update: [Verizon explanation](https://community.verizonwireless.com/t5/Samsung-Galaxy-S-Series/I-did-the-update-today-now-I-have-this-triangle-with-two-arrows/td-p/1003041)

Answer (score 0):

Data saver icon, it is displayed when you turn on data saver

Answer (score 0):

This is a data saver icon. If you don't want to see this, you can turn it off in settings.